# protobuf.net via multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, protocol-buffers

I want to deserialize lots of data using protobuf.net, but I found it cannot improve throughput via multi-threading.

my testing scenario:

1. single-thread, CPU load is 25% (1/4 cpu resource)
2. single-thread, 4 processes, cpu load is 9x % (4/4 cpu resource)
3. 4 threads, 1 process, cpu load is 30% ~ 60%

that's, protobuf cannot fully utilize cpu resource under multi-threading.

### Here is my code

```
    private static void DeSerialize()
    {
        while (true)
        { 
            Dictionary<string, byte[]>  cache ;
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out cache))
            {
                foreach (byte[] unit in cache.Values)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(unit))
                    {
                        CommonUtil.DeSerializeBuf<User>(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
    }

    private static void DeSerializeThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Thread a = new Thread(DeSerialize);
            a.Start();
        }
    }
```

How can protobuf.net fully utilize multiple CPU resources via multi-threading? multi-process is not acceptable in my case.

my code for testing the Parallel:

```
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<string>(stream, "some value which is awesome" + i);
            byte[] buffer = stream.ToArray();
            dic.Add("key" + i, buffer);
        }

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Restart();
        Console.Write("start parallel..");

        var result = dic.AsParallel().Select(p => ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<string>(new MemoryStream(p.Value))).ToList();
        var p1 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("end parallel " + p1);

        watch.Restart();
        Console.Write("start sequential..");

        var result2 = dic.Select(p => CommonUtil.DeSerializeBuf<string>(new MemoryStream(p.Value))).ToList();
        var p2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("end parallel " + p2);
```

thanks.

Comment: did you try to use Parallel or changing your code for async?

Comment: I will have to look at the specific example on a PC, but: protobuf-net is designed to be fully concurrent / thread-safe without blocking issues. BTW: how many cores do you have?

Comment: I have 4 cores in my pc. I have try other cpu-busy action than protobuf. for example, loop create objects, I can get more than 80% cpu load under "4 threads, 1 process" scenario. That's why I am wondering that the issue may exist in protobuf implement.

Comment: there is actually no issue with protobuffer, try my example I posted in my response below and use the Parallel approach in your code, you'll see that it will utilize your processor to almost 90%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a short example of how to use Linq As parallel, maybe this helps

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    dic.Add("key" + i, Serialize<string>("some value which is awesome" + i));
}

var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Restart();
Console.WriteLine("start parallel");

var result = dic.AsParallel().Select(p => Deserialize<string>(p.Value)).ToList();
var p1 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

watch.Restart();
Console.WriteLine("start sequential");

var result2 = dic.Select(p => Deserialize<string>(p.Value)).ToList();
var p2 = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

The difference is roughly 3 times faster with parallel execution on my machine. And also the processor utilization **is** different

Comment: i tried it but I got different result: no more than twice faster
--------------
start parallel..end parallel 7225
start sequential..end parallel 12310
--------------

Comment: of cause you'll get different results, it also depends on your PC, on target platform x86 is sometimes faster than x64, if you run the test in debug or release mode... Also you can tweek AsParallel and enfore parallel, set number of threads etc... So I suggest you to play around with it... and if you have another question, write a new one...